# Is there a way to solve this memory leak with my CompletableFuture code?

Tags: java, completable-future

We have a server that does backpressure in http1.1 (yes, it turns off sockets and clients actually freeze up waiting if we are under load...it's quite nice).  We do it in http2 as well without the http2 specification's doing backpressure in the http2 engine(ie. we don't need an backpressure there but we follow the spec and it also turns off sockets).  When I say 'turn off', I only mean it deregisters it so we stop reading the nic and our nic buffer fills and then clients nic fills until he freezes.

Anyways, we ran into an interesting issue and have been trying to solve it without a memory leak.  Our latest iteration was something like this

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> runLoop(List<T> newData, Session session, Processor<T> processFunction) {
    
    //All the below futures must be chained with previous ones in case previous ones are not
    //done which will serialize it all to be in sequence
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = session.getProcessFuture();
    
    for(T data : newData) {
        //VERY IMPORTANT: Writing the code like this would slam through calling process N times
        //BUT it doesn't give the clients a chance to set a flag between packets
        //Mainly done for exceptions and streaming so you can log exc, set a boolean so you
        //don't get 100 exceptions while something is happening like socket disconnect
        //In these 2 lines of code, processCorrectly is CALLED N times RIGHT NOW
        //The code below this only calls them right now IF AND ONLY IF the client returns
        //a completed future each time!!!
        //CompletableFuture<Void> messageFuture = processFunction.process(data);
        //future = future.thenCompose( f -> messageFuture);
        
        future = future.thenCompose( voidd -> processFunction.process(data));
    }
    
    session.setProcessFuturee(future);
    
    return future;
}
```

As data comes in runLoop is called for N data chunks.  runLoop is always called serially so we have no race conditions there.  We call runLoop X times.  The issue is that in the current code above processFunction.process MAY be called on a different thread (and in fact is quite frequently for our streaming endpoints only).

I am wondering how to cut the cord so to speak so that we stop chain.  commenting out session.setProcessFuture DOES stop the chain but the issue there is incoming data that comes in 2nd can then beat the data that came in first(and has but rarely).

The test I am using which if we comment out setProcessFuture bounces between 500MB and 6MB of memory on and off is the link below.  If I don't comment that out, it slowly uses up all 500MB.

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/core/core-util/src/test/java/org/webpieces/util/futures/TestLoopingChainMemory.java

Trying to not have the race condition and not have memory issues and also allow backpressure which is done using the future that we return from runLoop().  If there are too many unresolved, we stop feeding in traffic to runLoop.

FYI: thenCompose == scala's flatMap

EDIT: I had another idea and so I tried this but this failed as well.  The List size is typically pretty small in production so I didn't mind stacking up the futures in the loop but trying to cut the chain outside the loop to prevent the memory from adding up over time and never being cleaned...

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> runLoop(List<T> newData, Session session, Processor<T> processFunction) {
    
    //All the below futures must be chained with previous ones in case previous ones are not
    //done which will serialize it all to be in sequence
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = session.getProcessFuture();
    
    CompletableFuture<Void> newFuture = new CompletableFuture<Void>(); 
            
    for(T data : newData) {
        //VERY IMPORTANT: Writing the code like this would slam through calling process N times
        //BUT it doesn't give the clients a chance to seet a flag between packets
        //Mainly done for exceptions and streaming so you can log exc, set a boolean so you
        //don't get 100 exceptions while something is happening like socket disconnect
        //In these 2 lines of code, processCorrectly is CALLED N times RIGHT NOW
        //The code below this only calls them right now IF AND ONLY IF the client returns
        //a completed future each time!!!
        
        //This seems to have memory issues as well....
        //CompletableFuture<Void> temp = processFunction.process(data);
        //future = future.thenCompose(f -> temp);
        
        future = future.thenCompose( voidd -> processFunction.process(data));
    }
    
    future.handle((voidd, t) -> {
        if(t != null) {
            newFuture.completeExceptionally(t);
            return 0;
        }
        
        newFuture.complete(null);
        return 0;
    });
    
    //comment this out and memory leak goes away of course.......
    session.setProcessFuturee(newFuture);
    
    return newFuture;
}
```

EDIT: ok, I discovered that this line helps BUT I had to put code in to wait much longer for memory to cleanup.  It took a 'long' time to clean up and it memory goes down to 13MB.  **Now, I am wondering why cleanup is taking so long...perhaps objects made it through to older generations in the gc model**

```
future = future.thenComposeAsync( voidd -> processFunction.process(data), executor );
```

**THEN, I realized what if wait on my original code**.  This is where things got weird.  It only went back down to 196MB and stayed there.  I am not sure why or what the reference is.  I really don't see anything in MAT(eclipse) or I am using that tool wrong.

**Do I have a memory leak?  I am confused on this last result.  it should go down to < 20MB at least**

EDIT(addressing Shadov's answer): I believe the future returned is not chained to where it came from.  It is the 'tail' of the chain so to speak *I think*.  It's the opposite though, the future that created it is tied to that so that when the future that created it is done, it can resolve that future.  So in my mind, I am posting the tail of the list in the session each time(not creating a chain that is longer and longer).  The real issue with futures is the thread that references it and whether it was resolved.  This means the only one left referencing it is the anonymous Runnable that resolves it.  Once that happens, it should be able to resolve.

CompletableFuture is not even herein memory (MAT eclipse)..

[image]

**OMG, another major discovery.**. If I comment out this line

- future.complete(null);

then the program flies forever with memory bouncing between 180MB and 6MB.

Answer (score 1):

Not really good at this, but you are building bigger and bigger future and never stopping - no matter the size of the list, it's only gonna consume more and more memory, never releasing it.

You will see if you do in your test:

```java
chain.runLoop(list, s, p);
if(queue.size() == 0) {
  System.out.println("queue empty");
  s.setProcessFuturee(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null));
  rt.gc();
}
```

So in my opinion you need to use a different tool, `CompletableFuture` may be not strong enough for this. Maybe some full fledged reactive library, like rxjava or reactor?

Comment: thanks for the try!  I edited the post with something that seems to work.  I am trying to understand the 'chaining' myself.  I edited the bottom of my post to contain detail in case you are curious.

Comment: OMG.  If I comment out future.complete(null) which 'completes the future', then there is no memory issue and the loop flies forever bouncing between 180MB and 6MB over and over.  what in the world is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a git push and git commit.  There is no memory leak.  What is happening is that we slam the main thread so hard, it all accumulates........when giving time stuff to resolve, memory goes back to 6MB.  It just takes VERY long time but the logs helped see that easier AND I most importantly was missing the runtime.gc() call in a critical spot!!!!

soooo, with backpressure in place, we should have no issues since that makes all the futures resolves before adding load.